# Solve a differential equation using laplace transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am to solve the following differential equation using laplace transforms $y''+y'-6y=15u(x-2)$ with the intial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=2$

So far I have calcualted the following

$$L(y'')+L(y')-L(6y)=L(15u(x-2))$$
$$s^2L(y)-sy(0)-y'(0)+sL(y)-y(0)-6L(y)= 15(\frac{e^{-2s}}{s})$$
$$(s^2+s-6)L(y)-(1+s)y(0)-y'(0)= 15(\frac{e^{-2s}}{s})$$
$$(s^2+s-6)L(y)-(1+s)-2= 15(\frac{e^{-2s}}{s})$$
$$L(y)=\frac{15(\frac{e^{-2s}}{s})+3+s}{s^2+s-6}$$

I am unsure of where to go from here to solve the Differential equation

Comment: You should write $y'(0)$, not $s'(0)$, and then actually substitute the given initial conditions.

Comment: You need to take the Laplace transform of $u$ as well. I like to write $\hat{u}, \hat{y}$ etc. for the transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L(y)=\frac{15(\frac{e^{-2s}}{s})+3+s}{s^2+s-6}=\frac{15(\frac{e^{-2s}}{s})+3+s}{(s+3)(s-2)}$$
Decompose the fractions:
$$L(y)=15e^{-2s}\dfrac{1}{s(s+3)(s-2)}+\dfrac 1 {s-2}$$
$$L(y)=15e^{-2s}\left ( -\dfrac{1}{6s}+\dfrac {1}{15(s+3)}+\dfrac {1} {10(s-2)} \right)+\dfrac 1 {s-2}$$
$$L(y)=e^{-2s}\left ( -\dfrac{5}{2s}+\dfrac {1}{s+3}+\dfrac {3} {2(s-2)} \right)+\dfrac 1 {s-2}$$
Apply inverse Laplace transform now.